# Dropbox API List Folder and Folder recursive

Tags: dropbox-api

How to list the folder hierarchy and existens files inside Dropbox account?
The method below lists only the folders of the root directory. Anyone know the library will tell if there is something ready for such functionality?

```
    ListFolderResult result;
    try {
        result = client.files().listFolder(StringUtils.EMPTY);

        while (true) {
            for (Metadata metadata : result.getEntries()) {
                System.out.println(metadata.getPathLower());
            }

            if (!result.getHasMore()) {
                break;
            }
            result = client.files().listFolderContinue(result.getCursor());
        }
    } catch (DbxException exception) {
        System.out.println(exception.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `listFolder` is not recursive.

For a recursive listing, you should use [`ListFolderBuilder`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.0.x/com/dropbox/core/v2/files/ListFolderBuilder.html) and use `withRecursive` to set recursive to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I got what I needed with the following code. Thanks!

```
public void listFolderAndFiles() {

    try {
        ListFolderResult result = client.files().listFolderBuilder("").withIncludeDeleted(false).withRecursive(true).withIncludeMediaInfo(true)
                .start();

        // while (true) {
        List<Metadata> entries = result.getEntries();
        int idx = 0;

        for (Metadata metadata : entries) {
            if (metadata instanceof FolderMetadata) {
                System.out.println("" + ++idx + ": FOLDER = " + metadata.getPathDisplay());

            } else if (metadata instanceof FileMetadata) {
                System.out.println("" + ++idx + ": File = " + metadata.getPathDisplay());
            }

            // String filePath = metadata.getPathLower().replace(metadata.getName().toLowerCase(), "");
            // System.out.println(metadata.getPathLower());
            // System.out.println("FILE PATH" + filePath);
            // System.out.println("Dropbox" + ((FileMetadata) metadata).getRev());
            // System.out.println("Dropbox" + ((FileMetadata) metadata).getClientModified());
            // System.out.println("Dropbox" + ((FileMetadata) metadata).getMediaInfo());
            // System.out.println("Dropbox" + ((FileMetadata) metadata).getMediaInfo().getMetadataValue());
            // System.out.println("Dropbox" + ((FileMetadata) metadata).getSharingInfo());
        }
        // }

    } catch (DbxException exception) {
        throw new BusinessException("Não foi possivel obter dados do diretório.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jeremias's solution works, but you might allso want to check if there are more results pending in the returned ListFolder. there is a cap of 10,000 items per query.

```
while(true){  

    ListFolderResult result = client.files().listFolderBuilder(path)  
         .withRecursive(true) 
         .start();

    List<Metadata> entries = result.getEntries(); 
    for (Metadata metadata : entries) { ... do your logic here }

    if(result.getHasMore()){
         result = client.files().listFolderContinue(result.getCursor);
    } else {
         break; //no more entries to process
    }


}
```

also remember to do the try-catch.

Answer (score 0):

Use `listFolderBuilder(path)` in stead of `listFolder`, like below:

```
ListFolderResult result = client.files().listFolderBuilder(path)  
         .withRecursive(true) 
         .start();
```